# Facebook Share Permalink Javascript href

Tags: permalinks, facebook, social-sharing

Hi I am trying to get a facebook share button to share the current post permalink page to no avail. Anyone help?

```
  <?php var $perma = '<?= get_the_permalink(); ?>';?>
  <a href="javascript:fbShare('<?php echo $perma ?>', 'FB Share', 'Facebook share popup', '<?php echo $perma ?>', 520, 350)">Share</a>
```

JS

```
   function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
    var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
    var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + title + '&p[summary]=' + descr + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width=' + winWidth + ',height=' + winHeight);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good I have figured it out

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>', 'FB Share', 'Facebook share popup', '<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>', 520, 350)">
```